# String manipulation splitting strings

Tags: c#, string, split

Create an application that accepts into a textbox a person’s first given and family names
(with one or more spaces between them) and when a “Separate Names” button is clicked
the names are displayed separately with appropriate labelling. For example, entry of
“Bob Brown”
will result in an output of Family Name : Brown Given Name : Bob

here's my code:

```
string str=textBox1.Text;
string[] name = str.Split(' ');
MessageBox.Show("Family Name: " + name[1] + "\t" + "Given Name: " + name[0]);
```

how do I do this if there are more than one space in the textbox?
If there is more than one space it shows up like this:
Family name:       Given name:bob

Answer (score 3):

Did you try?

```
StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
```

[stringsplitoptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

As PawanS suggested you can use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` as follows:

```
string str=textBox1.Text;
string[] name = str.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
MessageBox.Show("Family Name: " + name[1] + "\t" + "Given Name: " + name[0]);
```

May I also remind you to confirm that the array actually contains at least two items by checking the aray's `Length` property to avoid getting an exception on invalid input.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the multiple spaces using:

```
string str = Regex.Replace(textBox1.Text, @"\s+", " ");
```

And then proceed with your code:

```
string[] name = str.Split(' ');
MessageBox.Show("Family Name: " + name[1] + "\t" + "Given Name: " + name[0]);
```

**The advantage of this method is that it will remove any kind of whitespace (e.g. tabs, newlines, etc.) and replace them with a single space**

Answer (score 1):

You should remove all empty entries using [StringSplitOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) in your string and split your string by yout character. For example:

```
string str=textBox1.Text;
var name = str.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 

MessageBox.Show("Family Name: " + name[1] + "\t" + "Given Name: " + name[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to use LINQ perhaps?

Example:

```
var lastName = name.Last();
var firstNames = name.Take(name.Count()-1);
MessageBox.Show("Family Name: " + lastName + "\t" + "Given Name: " + string.Join(" ", firstNames.ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegExp to replace all duplicate white space before Split string

```
yourStr = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(yourStr ,@"\s+"," ");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    string str=textBox1.Text;

    string firstName = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(' '));
    string lastName = str.Replace(" ", "").Replace(firstName, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean that it is possible to write input data like:

```
"John   Doe" //more than one space
```

?
Try to do this:

```
var input = "John   Doe";
var arr = s.Split(' ').Where(x=>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToArray();
MessageBox.Show("Family Name: " + arr[1] + "\t" + "Given Name: " + arr[0]);
```